# Word for opposite parallel vectors

Tags: vocabulary, mathematics

Given two points, A and B, there are two vectors: A-->B and A<--B which are parallel but pointing in opposite directions. I remember learning as a kid a word which simply defines the line upon which the vectors lie and another which defines the direction the vectors move along the line, something like "A-->B and A<--B have the same XXX, but opposite YYY." Can anyone fill in these blanks?

Comment: All I can find is "opposite vector" or "negative vector". Is it something other than that?

Comment: I expect you would get an answer quicker on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Catija No, I distinctly remember the structure being as given: "A-->B and A<--B have the same XXX, but opposite YYY".

Comment: Opposite sense.

Comment: Your title doesn't clearly reflect the content of the body, and I think my answer reflects the title more than the body. Is my answer appropriate, or should I delete it?

Comment: @MattGutting Oh bugger. Hadn't noticed that. Your answer is more than appropriate. It is, I would say, the correct answer to the question posed in the title. That being said, I was in fact looking for meuh's answer. But please don't delete your answer, which I believe is just as valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

same magnitude and opposite direction

Answer (score 5):

The vectors are called [*antiparallel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparallel_(mathematics)#Antiparallel_vectors):

> In a Euclidean space, two directed line segments, often called *vectors* in applied mathematics, are antiparallel, if they are supported by parallel lines and have opposite directions.

*Note:* Two antiparallel vectors need not have the same magnitude (i.e. length); they can be of any length.

Answer (score 0):

same axis but opposite direction?

Comment: Axis? For a vector? Never heard that used in this context.